# Vanilla Javascript equivalent of jQuery not()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, javascript-objects

This is what I'm doing in jQuery:

```
var text2 = $(node).not("span").text();
console.log(text2);
```

How do I do this same thing in pure javascript?

I know how to get elements in javascript, but not how to ignore elements and select the rest

```
var spans = node.getElementsByTagName('span');
```

I need to get every elements within `node` that does not contain a `<span>`

Here is my HTML

```
                     <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span>Farley</span>
                                <div class="table-row__expanded-content">
                                    <data-key>Sex: </data-key> <data-value>Male</data-value><br />
                                    <data-key>DOB: </data-key> <data-value>12/08/2010</data-value> <br />
                                    <data-key>Weight: </data-key> <data-value>20 lbs</data-value> <br />
                                    <data-key>Location: </data-key> <data-value>Kennel 2B</data-value> <br />
                                    <data-key>Temperament: </data-key> <data-value>Aggresive</data-value> <br />
                                    <data-key>Allergies: </data-key> <data-value>Sulfa, Penicillin, Peanuts</data-value>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>Cunningham, Stephanie</td>
                            <td>Dog</td>
                            <td>Pomeranian</td>
                            <td>PQRST1234567</td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: you can't with vanilla. you take the gEBTN() results, loop on them, and filter out the stuff you don't want.

Comment: `node.querySelectorAll(":not(span)")`

Comment: That's not what `not` does.

Comment: One question is why? Is this just an exercise? Do you mean all direct child elements of node that don't contain span?

Comment: I thought not filtered the current jquery object of elements that matched it. So wouldn't $(node).not("span") just filter any span elements out of that jquery object, not look at elements in that object which contain a span element?

Comment: Why did I get so many down votes? AthiestP3eace, that's what it does in my script.

Comment: The purpose of doing this is to minimize dependency on jQuery. I mean all nodes not contained within a child element - text directly in them as in `<td>text</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or a quick example that runs in a console on this page:

```
var startNode = jQuery("li.related-site").get(0); // quick jQ to get a testable node.
var spanLess = [];
var child = startNode.firstChild;
while(child){
   if(child.nodeType == 1){
       var anySpans = child.getElementsByTagName('span');
       if(!anySpans.length) spanLess.push(child);
   } 
   child = child.nextSibling;
}
spanLess;
```

Based on your comment that you are trying to extract values for use with tablesorter what you might also find useful is a function to extract the text values from a node regardless of markup:

```
function extractText(node){
    if(node.nodeType == 3) return node.nodeValue.trim();
    if(node.nodeType == 1){
        var buf = [];
        var child = node.firstChild;
        while(child){
            var val = extractText(child);
            if(val) buf.push(val);
            child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        return buf.join(' ');
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: How about if the child contents are not inside an element? The node is <td> and the text is directly inside that for the spanless.

Comment: Not sure I follow your question. If the node is a td and has only text content then the code above would work. You can ignore the `var startNode...` part because your sample indicated you already had a node to work with. If you are just trying to easily test a node you already have to see if it has any spans just do `if(!node.getElementsByTagName('span').length){ ... process the node }`

Comment: Of course if your requirements change where you have to look at classes then: `if(!node.querySelectorAll('span.interest').length){ ... process the node }`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to get it working based on your code. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try [**querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

```js
 var notSpans = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].querySelectorAll(':not(span)');

 for (var i = 0; i < notSpans.length; i++) {
   notSpans[i].style.color = 'green';
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>not a span</p>
  <span>a span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i was thinking the same, but what if span is deep? "every elements within node that does not contain a <span>" would mean a lot of nesting and repeated sub-tags...

Comment: My example handles the case where the spans are deep. Which to use depends on what the OP actually wanted.

Comment: This works when my text is within an element inside <td>. But my text is directly inside <td> so there is not a selector. See updated original post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bknights, I was able to modify his answer to work for my needs.

My full fuction is as follows:

```
    var myTextExtraction = function (node) {
    //console.log(node);

    var child = node.firstChild;
    while (child) {
        if (node.getElementsByTagName('span').length) {
            childValue = child.nextSibling.innerHTML;
            console.log(childValue);
        }
        else {
            childValue = child.nodeValue
            console.log(childValue);
        }
        return childValue;
    }
}
```

Then I create the `node` object with the tablesorter plugin:

```
// Load the table sorter
$(".table").tablesorter(
    {
        textExtraction: myTextExtraction
    }
);
```

This loops through and outputs the text inside `<td><span>mytext</span></td>` as well as the text in `<td>myothertext<td>`. I'm using this for the jquery TableSorter plugin to work with complex data inside `<td>`s

Comment: Glad you found that helpful. It would be great if you would mark my answer as correct. Also unless you are very sure of the format of your data it sounds like what you might really be interested in is a function that extracts the text value from the td regardless of markup. See my edited answer